# Using both command substitution and executing a shell within GNU "find" exec command

Tags: bash, find

I am a bash newbie, and I'm trying to do something that seems fairly straightforward but am having issues.

I am trying to search for a file with a pretty generic but nonunique name (e.g. analysis.uniqueExt, but also maybe sorted_result.uniqueExt) that can be within one specific subdirectory of a directory that was found from a different 'find' query. Then I would like to copy that file to my personal directory whilst also renaming the file to something more descriptive that hints to its origin location.

Here is an example of what I have tried:

```
case=/home/data/ABC_123 # In reality this is coming from a different query successfully
specific_id=ABC_123 # This was extracted from the previous variable
OUTDIR=/my/personal/directory

mkdir -p $OUT_DIR/$this_folder

find $case/subfolder/ -type f -name "*.uniqueExt" -exec sh -c 'cp "$1" ${OUT_DIR}/${specific_id}/$(basename "$1")' sh {} \;
```

This doesn't work because OUT_DIR and specific_id are not scoped in the inner shell created by the -exec command.

So I tried to do this another way:

```
find $case/subfolder/ -type f -name "*.uniqueExt" -exec cp {} ${OUT_DIR}/${specific_id}/$(basename {}) \;
```

However now I cannot extract the basename of the file found in the 'find' query as I have not invoked a shell to do so.

Is there a way I can either properly scope my variables in example #1 or execute the basename function in example #2 to accomplish this? Or maybe there is a totally different solution (possibly involving multiple -exec calls? Or maybe just piping the find results to xargs?).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You need to export the variables since you're using them in a different shell process than the one you assigned them in.

Exporting variables makes them available in descendant processes.

```
export specific_id=ABC_123 # This was extracted from the previous variable
export OUTDIR=/my/personal/directory
```

However, you don't really need to use the shell for this. You can use

```
find $case/subfolder/ -type f -name "*.uniqueExt" -exec cp -t "$OUTDIR/$specific_id/" {} +
```

You don't have to call `basename` yourself, because copying a file to a target directory automatically uses the basename as the destination filename.

In my version, I use the `-t` option so I can put the destination directory first. This allows it to use the `+` variant to put all the found filenames in a single command, rather than running `cp` separately for each file.

Comment: More precisely: `export`ing them makes them (well, copies of them) available to *subprocesses* of the process that exported them. Since `find` is a subprocess of the shell running the script, and `find` runs `sh -c ...` as a subprocess of itself, that subprocess shell will inherit the values. (I'm adding this because a lot of people expect exported variable to pass to *parent* processes, and that just doesn't happen.)

Comment: I added some clarification.