# Copying files using the find command

Tags: linux, find, cp

I am trying to copy a series of files that match a specific pattern I give. There may be more than one match

```
    find "$ORIG_DATA_DIR/D_Data/$TASK/$SUB_ID" -name "$SUB_ID*.edf" -type f -exec cp {} "$OUTPUT_DIR/$SUB_ID/sub-${SUB_ID}_task-${TASK}_$(basename {})" \;
```

The above `basename` command doesn't seem to execute, and instead gives me the full path.

I also cannot use the `-execdir` option because I need the full name for copying.

I should also point out that I have had trouble using `sh -c` to do it because I have multiple variables in the output path.

What is the best way to do this find command in a single line?

Comment: Variables and command substitution are done by the original shell, not after substituting `{}`. `-exec` doesn't execute the command using the shell.

Comment: edited the question to show that I am concatenating some string flags to the beginning of the base name

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67204886/using-both-command-substitution-and-executing-a-shell-within-gnu-find-exec-com/67204916#67204916 for how to use variables with `-exec sh -c`

Comment: "What is the best way to do this find command in a single line?" write a small helper script that forms your destination path with `basename` and do the copy in the helper script. Then you simply call the helper with `-exec yourhelper.sh '{}' \;`